# How to measure the total time of an asynchronous process using micrometer and prometheus (PromQL)?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, micrometer

I have the following microservices scenario

Microservice 1

1 - Collect a System.getCurrentTimeMillis

2 - Generate an id after an operation in the DB

**3 - This step should send the ID and the initial time of the operation to Prometheus**

Microservice 7

1 - Finish processing the message with the ID generated in the first microservice

2 - Collect a System.getCurrentTimeMillis

**3 - This step should send the ID and the final time of the operation to Prometheus**

How can I implement step 3 and then use PromQL to measure the total transaction time?

The data can be displayed in prometheus as a histogram as in the display of http requests if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you've described isn't really how Prometheus is intended to be used. You are describing logging or tracing. (See [Zipkin](https://zipkin.io/), [Jaeger](https://www.jaegertracing.io/), etc)

Metrics sent to Prometheus are in aggregate. So you won't (typically) be able to tease out individual calls. (Any hacks used to make it work won't scale very far)

Micrometer/Prometheus would be best used to track the aggregate durations the individual steps of your processing are taking.

Comment: I just forgot to comment, but I can't use opentracing (Zipkin, Jaeger, etc ...) between my services there is a step where the request is sent to a third party system that does not allow me to send the associated headers and the body needs be standardized in the format defined by them, precisely for that reason I am looking for some other option.